# Method not visible at runtime

Tags: go

I have following code structure

```
❯ tree -L 2                    
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── cmd
│   ├── app
├── coverage.out
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── internal
│   ├── context
│   ├── pubsub
│   └── test_helpers
├── pkg
│   ├── <service_name>
└── tools
    ├── random.go
    └── mymethod.go
```

Here is the code for `random.go` file

```golang
package main

func main() {
    SayHi()
}
```

The method `SayHi` is defined in `mymethod.go` like this

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// SayHi comment
func SayHi() {
    fmt.Printf("saying hi ...")
}
```

When I run my `random.go`, I get an error that `SayHi` is undefined. Both of these files are under same package i.e., `tools` so i am not sure what i am doing wrong. Do i have to import it differently?

Comment: which command do you use to run it?

Comment: Never, literally **never** use `go  run` to execute Go code unless you _really_ know what you are doing. go run is a loaded footgun.

Answer (score 1):

The `go run` command runs either an entire package or a single file. If you only specified a single file, it will not load up the entire folder. That's why if you run `go run random.go`, it will not load up the `mymethod.go` file at.

If you only have one `main()` function in the "tools" folder (supposedly a `package main`), you may simply do this in that folder:

```sh
go run .
```

If you only need the 2 files but not the other files:

```sh
go run random.go mymethod.go
```

Comment: I am using vscode default launch.json to run it. It is using `${file}` placeholder to run the code. Should I replace it with all files?

Comment: Please find a way to reference the folder instead of the file.